# ExtJs NumberField

Tags: javascript, extjs, input, numbers

I am using ExtJs NumberField. The good thing is it validates that only numbers are entered.
But I want a hyphen as well. How could I go about editing the javascript

```
  var <portlet:namespace/>issueNoField = new Ext.form.NumberField({  //This takes only numbers
             fieldLabel: 'Issue No',
             width: 120,
             displayField: 'Enter no',  
             valueField:'IssNo'
         });
```

Comment: What's up with the `<portlet:namespace/>` thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var <portlet:namespace/>issueNoField = new Ext.form.TextField({  //This takes only numbers
  fieldLabel: 'Issue No',
  width: 120,
  regex: /[1-9-]*/
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "baseChars" option.

```
     var <portlet:namespace/>issueNoField = new Ext.form.NumberField({  //This takes only numbers
         fieldLabel: 'Issue No',
         width: 120,
         displayField: 'Enter no',  
         valueField:'IssNo'
         baseChars: "0123456789-"
     });
```

Comment: I deployed it, its not accepting. The issue is NumberField validates at the form level itself that numbers are entered. It wont even get inside to check the baseChars. I will try with regular text field and use baseChars.

Comment: You can't use baseChars for regular text field because baseChars is defined by NumberField class.

Comment: It should works. I always use baseChars for NubmerField. Anyway you can use simple text field with regex validation.

Comment: If you want a hyphen (not a 'minus' in front of a number) in the input, then it is no longer a numeric input. Use TextField with regex.

Comment: Can you help me with using simple text field and regex to allow hyphen in the middle of number. I am new to JS

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ui2)

Its better to use the textfield and adding the maskRe attribute as

`maskRe: /^[0-9 -]$/`

Answer (score 0):

Is the hyphen merely conventional, as in a US zip code (99999-9999)?  In that case, you should accept only numeric input, insert the hyphen when that position is reached, and ignore any non-numeric characters.

If they hyphen is significant, so that "12-345" and "123-45" are different inputs, then you are reading text and not a number.  However, that would be an extremely unfriendly system.

Answer (score 0):

The Regex attribute never worked for me, I used the code below instead:

```
maskRe: /[1-9-]/,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
xtype: 'textfield',
mask: '(999) 999-9999'
}
```

What I'm proposing here is that we use a `text field` and put a mask to it to capture only numeric values in the desires format.

You can mask it according to your needs.

**For Example:**

```
'9999999999'
'999-999-9999'
```

[More info](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136002-Mask-for-TextField) This will give the phone number in the format you want

Comment: It's Better to describe more details about your solution , by just including external links which maybe unavailable all the time , you are not helping much !

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `allowExponential` config of your numberfield to false. By default it is true and it adds `'e+-'` and the `decimalSeparator` as valid characters.

It's true. The source check the source.

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Number3.html#Ext-form-field-Number-cfg-allowExponential
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/src/Number.js-3.html#Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-allowExponential